# Ajax check registered email on form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've taken this script to check if email is registered in DB using ajax. The problem is:
It's just checking once, if user insert a registered email and then insert another email the var in checkemail.php do not change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x_timer;    
        $("#email").keyup(function (e){
            clearTimeout(x_timer);
            var email = $(this).val();
            x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
                check_username_ajax(email);
            }, 600);
        }); 

        function check_username_ajax(email){
            $.post('checkemail.php', {'email':email}, function(data) {
                $("#user-result").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" /><span id="user-result"></span>
```

checkemail.php

```
<?php
    require'conexao.php';
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $SQL = "SELECT email FROM clients WHERE email = '" . $email . "'";
    $check = @mysql_query($SQL) or die("Erro no banco de dados!");
    $result = @mysql_num_rows($check);

    if($result){
        $emailstate = "1";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("O E-mail informado já está cadastrado.");</script>
        <input type="radio" id="emailstate" name="emailstate" value="<?php echo $emailstate; ?>" style="display:none;" checked>';
    } else {
        $emailstate = "0";
        echo '<input type="radio" id="emailstate" name="emailstate" value="<?php echo $emailstate; ?>" style="display:none;" checked>';
    }
?>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you checked the JavaScript console for errors? Also, are you aware that functions like `mysql_query` are to be removed in the upcoming PHP version?

Comment: No errors, I guess its just not checking again after retype another email.

Comment: why re u using that timeout?? why just dont validate on blur or on every keyup??

Comment: Can you please teach me? I'm totally new in javascript

Comment: doesn't make sense using `keyup` ... user needs to input the whole email address if you are wanting to see if it is unique or not

Comment: I dont know javascript. It's a code I copied from a forum. I just know it works but dont know how

Comment: Then its code you need to study and work out what it is doing. The idea is we help with code issues, but not **I copied this and dont understand it can you fix it as per my specifications** type coding. [here is the jQuery Manual to get you started](https://api.jquery.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question shows code that doesn't make much sense, i.e. not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve, however this will work to get you on the right track.

checkemail.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    // Lookup
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $sql = "SELECT email, username FROM clients WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    // Format the response package and send back to calling .js function
    $response = new stdClass();
    if (!$result) {
        $response->error = "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
        exit;
    } else {
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($response->exists = mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            // If account exists, get username and add to response data
            $response->username = $row['username'];
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
?>
```

client-side html/js:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#email").blur(function (e) {
            var email = $(this).val();
            check_username_ajax(email);
        });

        function check_username_ajax(email) {
            $.post('checkemail.php', {'email': email}, function (data) {
                //uncomment the line below to inspect the response in js console/firebug etc
                //console.log(data);
                if (data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
                    $("#user-result").html(data.error);
                } else {
                    if (data.exists == '1') {
                        $("#user-result").html('Account exists, username is: ' + data.username);
                    } else {
                        $("#user-result").html('Account does not exist');
                    }
                }
            }, "json");
        }
    });
</script>
<div>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
    <span id="user-result"></span>
</div>
```

You could add other properties to the PHP response object like this: `$response->username` and then access the variable in the js ajax/post response like this: `data.username`.

As the other commenters have said, loose the 'setTimeout' with the arbitrary delay, it's not really applicable here, perhaps you will find onBlur more appropriate as shown or perhaps wrap into a full form - as it stands it is not clear what your intended usage is.

Comment: It is much better than the first. Thank you so much. How can I send a var $error if email in DB and $ok if email isnt in db?

Comment: @PampulhaTech My answer already describes this:

"You could add other properties to the PHP response object like this: `$response->username` and then access the variable in the js ajax/post response like this: `data.username`"

You would just add any data you like to the response and can access it as shown here. Please upvote my answer if it has been useful for you. Thanks.

Comment: @PampulhaTech Just updated my answer with more detail, providing a more comprehensive example. Please take the time to evaluate this and if it answers your question, upvote and mark as accepted please. Thanks :)

Comment: I got it now. Thank you so much. Just one last question: Where is "Account does not exist" can I add a html code?

Comment: @PampulhaTech No problem! This is now handled in the response at the client-side in js-code: `if (data.exists == '1') {
$("#user-result").html('Account exists, username is: ' + data.username);
}`

Comment: Hey bro. I've solved it. Check my answer :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

checkemail.php

```
<?php
    require'conexao.php';
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM clients WHERE email = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "' LIMIT 1";
    $echk=mysql_query($sql);
    $ecount=mysql_num_rows($echk);
    if($ecount!=0)
    {
        $emailstate = "1";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("O E-mail informado já está cadastrado.");</script>
        <input type="radio" id="emailstate" name="emailstate" value="<?php echo $emailstate; ?>" style="display:none;" checked>';
    } else {
        $emailstate = "0";
        echo '<input type="radio" id="emailstate" name="emailstate" value="<?php echo $emailstate; ?>" style="display:none;" checked>';
    }
?>
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function checkMailStatus(){
            var email=$("#email").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                    url:'checkemail.php',
                    data:{email: email},
                    success:function(msg){
                        $("#user-result").html(msg);
                    }
             });
            }
        </script>
```

html

```
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" onblur="checkMailStatus()"/><span id="user-result"></span>
```